# react-redux-form: validation of forms in accordion / validation of unmounted forms

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-redux-form

This question is about handling validation of multi-part forms using the library react-redux-form.

The issue: I have 3 forms and a container wrapping them. The forms are submitted from the container. On mounting the container, only 1 form is shown (mounted) and the rest are hidden (unmounted). The "valid" state of each of the forms is shown to the user.

```
if (current === 1) {
  <MyFirstForm/>
} 
if (current === 2) {
  <MySecondForm/>
} 
if (current === 3) {
  <MyThirdForm/>
} 
<button disabled={formsNotValid}> Submit </button>
```

At this point - after mounting - nothing has been validated.
I need to perform a validation action at this point on the unmounted forms. This is because the form data is sometimes loaded from localStore.

The library, by default seems to set all the "valid" states to "true" apart from the mounted form which is validated on mount and set accordingly. So currently i am performing a setValidity action to set everything to false (but this is overwriting the initial validation action on the mounted form). But this feels a bit of a hack - i should be actually validating the forms...?

There is a validate action: (https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/api/actions.html#actions-validate)

But from what i understand this requires the user to pass all the validation rules. I guess i'm ok to refactor to do this, but i have currently defined all the validation rules on the fields.

```
          <Control.text
            model=".test"
            component={Text}
            placeholder="test"
            validators={{
              required: val => val,
            }}
          />
```

Is the correct way to deal with this problem by passing all the validation rules for all the fields in the validate action on the container? I mean ... thats makes sense i guess, no validation rules are stored in the redux store so technically no validation is defined when the form is unmounted.

Perhaps the pattern is wrong? I should have had a  component wrapping the conditional and only loading different sections of the form? But i think if i did this validations would occur on fields that weren't mounted... which would cause other problems.

Hopefully someone else has come across a similar situation and wouldn't mind giving some advice on how they solved it.

Thanks
Geoff